# WPF : Use another project from online into mine

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to add analog click into my project , I'v found 2 project online :

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfClock.aspx

http://blog.aaltra.eu/en/tech/createanalogclockinwpf

They are both old visual studio version ( 2008 i think ) , there is a conversion when open in 2010 , there is no .dll which I can  take into my project.... I dont want to copy the source files...

How to use it in my project?

Answer (score 0):

There are no DLLs until you build the projects. Either add them to your solution and then add project references to them in your main project, or build the 3rd-party projects independently - which will output DLLs to their output folders, likely *ProjectName/Debug/bin* - and reference those DLLs from your main project.

Comment: There wasn't any .dll after the build. I added the proejct to mine and added the "project refernce" 1) after delete the another-project , the refernce is also getting delete (I dont want the project, just the dll) 2) now How i use it?1

Comment: djacobson gives you two options, if you don't want the first then do the second.

Comment: I tried the second option , I have the reference , now .. how I use it? How I insert the xaml from the added-project to mine? The problem is that both the online projects are WPF Window App , so there is no dll and it seems there is a problem to host a window into a window...